# Is "Permutation Test" sufficient for a/b testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

I read the "Practical Statistics for Data Scientists" book which is written by Peter Bruce and Andrew Bruce. In this book, the hypothesis testing is only realized with permutation test. If I searched the web, there are formulas, also I did not see too many permutation test blog articles. I want to ask that the permutation test is enough to analyzing a/b experiment data, or do I need different thing ?

Sorry for my grammatical mistakes, my native language is not English.

Comment: In what way do you mean "sufficient"? In terms of power, or something else?

Comment: rejecting the null hypothesis, I also curious about in terms of power.

Comment: Permutation tests are often useful when assumptions of more standard and familiar tests cannot be met. Suppose A and B yield different responses? If that is important, in what way. Would you be interested in differences between means? between variances? between distributional shapes? // If you have huge amounts of data it may be enough to show numerical and graphical summaries. Many actions taken on the basis of differences between A and B have been expensive mistakes, because a 2nd A/B test at different time / in different climate have contradicted the 1st. ...

Comment: ... Vast differences in survey results can stem from innocently changing one or two words in ways that are not intended to change the meaning, but that happen to trigger unanticipated emotional responses. No two questions on a questionnaire can ever be assumed to be viewed independently by subjects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately permutation tests are a type of statistical significance test; we could have use bootstrapping if we want another frequentist non-parametric approach (e.g. see "*[How do bootstrap and permutation tests work?](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-31/issue-3/How-do-bootstrap-and-permutation-tests-work/10.1214/aos/1056562462.full)"* (2003) by Janssen & Pauls for a relevant comparison). Whether or not they should be used instead of standard parametric tests is an question that is really old (e.g. see [*The large-sample power of tests based on permutations of observations*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-23/issue-2/The-Large-Sample-Power-of-Tests-Based-on-Permutations-of/10.1214/aoms/1177729436.full) (1952) by Hoeffding as an early attempt to use permutation tests instead of standard parametric tests of hypothesis testing) and doesn't really have a definitive answer. It might be even argued that permutation tests construct a null when there is not a well-defined one while parametric test never shy away from the explicit definition of a null - see Chapt. 17 *Large-Scale Hypothesis Testing and FDRs* in [*Computer Age Statistical Inference*](https://hastie.su.domains/CASI/) (2016) by Efron & Hastie for a more careful discussion on that.

Permutation tests therefore are not a statistical *panacea*. As such, think the question should not be if "*permutation testing*" is sufficient for A/B testing but if "*hypothesis testing*" is sufficient for A/B testing. In that case, the answer is *no*. We need regression analysis, we need to be able to be certain that there are not [confounding variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding) that we accidentally ignored or unexpectedly included, and so forth. *Yes*,  permutation testing is enough in the majority of cases where everything has gone as planned, we observe no [seasonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonality), no primacy or [novelty effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelty_effect), we have limited [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias), and what not. In order cases, I would strongly urge you to educate yourself in [regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) and general [experimental design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments) principles too. Recently, [causal inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_inference) has also come to the foreground as a mean to get even greater insights by our observational data but that is a step following standard regression analysis techniques.

Finally, it is notable that while permutation tests are indeed a type of hypothesis testing, A/B testing is a type of an experimentation approach to maximise business goals and using statistical hypothesis testing is only part of the methodology required (parametric or non-parametric, frequentist or Bayesian, etc). For example, [multi-armed bandits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) is another experimentation approach to solve the same problem. Ultimately what we want to maximise our utility functions (e.g. time on client, user expenditure, etc.) That is not what hypothesis testing is aiming to do as it is much more interested in the truthfulness of a hypothesis.

Comment: I think that analyzing the A/B test is only comprised of hypothesis testing. We get better metrics than control group, I think that only need is understanding whether this result is by chance or not. But you said that analyzing a/b is more comprehensive than that. How can I learn other things, do you have any resources about that ?

Comment: The problem with A/B tests is they start are being equivalent to randomised control trials (RCTs) but very often end up unlikely RCTs having a lot of external factors affecting them - in contrast with RCTs, the Internet is not a well-controlled environment. This is where regression analysis (and subsequent techniques like Causal Analysis) come in play; for example a great reference to start with is: [Regression Methods in Biostatistics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-1353-0) by Vittinghoff et al. It marries how experimental design connects with regression analysis nicely.

Comment: I also found [Data analysis using regression and multilevel/hierarchical models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/) by Gelman and Hill, invaluable for the analysis of  *A/B* tests at work. Ultimately A/B tests are pseudo-observational data, and in most cases "adding more covariates" helps with the power of the test rather than hinters it.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the two fictitious normal samples below, in which
sample sizes, sample means, and sample variances all differ.

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = rnorm( 70, 50,   5)
x2 = rnorm(100, 53.2, 9)
```

Someone who did not notice the different variances, might
do a pooled 2-sample t test, find no difference in means
at the 5% level, and conclude nothing interesting is going on.

```
t.test(x1, x2, var.eq=T)$p.val
[1] 0.07286454

summary(x1); length(x1);  sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  38.72   45.22   49.70   49.55   52.70   60.60 
[1] 70           # sample size
[1] 5.366852     # sample standard deviation

summary(x2); length(x2);  sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  28.89   45.37   51.90   51.87   57.64   77.20 
[1] 100
[1] 9.805152

stripchart(list(x1,x2), ylim=c(.5,2.5), pch="|")
```

[image]

However, a more appropriate Welch 2-sample t test (that does not
assume equal variances) does find a difference in means at the 5% level.

```
t.test(x1, x2)$p.val
[1] 0.04866419
```

And (assuming normality) an F-test finds a highly significant difference
between sample variances.

```
var.test(x1,x2)$p.val
[1] 3.605368e-07
```

Even the notoriously underpowered Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
finds that the two population distributions are not quite the same.

```
ks.test(x1,x2)$p.val
[1] 0.04495466
```

A nonparametric Wilcoxon Rank Sum test finds a significant difference.
However, owing to the different shapes of the samples, this cannot be
considered as a test for difference in medians.

```
wilcox.test(x1, x2)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x1 and x2
W = 2878, p-value = 0.04909
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Nor is it clear that the (barely significant) 'location shift' really amounts to stochastic
domination by the second (larger) sample [brown in the empirical
CDF plots below.]

```
hdr = "ECDFs of Samples 1 [blue] and 2 [brown]"
plot(ecdf(x1), col="blue", main=hdr)
 lines(ecdf(x2), col="brown")
```

[image]

Furthermore, [permutation tests](http://jse.amstat.org/v18n1/eudey.pdf) using various metrics could be
proposed, which might show a difference in population means---or not.

Depending on what you mean by "better," you might find a standard
or permutation test to support that either A or B is "better"--or that there is not enough "difference" between them to be of practical
importance.

Comment: I mean, suggesting to take an A/B testing business decision with a p-value of $0.045$ is a bit hard-core... For all intended purposes what is described here, is a "get more data" situation. Nice points (so +1) but I find them a bit tangential to the OP's question.

Comment: My main point is that the P-values differ surprisingly, not so much that they happen to differ on either side of the usual 5% level. For more context, see my comments under the Question, which I did not repeat in my Answer (and maybe should have).

Comment: Do they differ surprisingly? 0.07286 & 0.04909, 0.04866, 0.04495 seem awfully close. Effectively as soon we we discard equal variances we got practically the same (marginally significant at $\alpha=0.05$) result. (Yeah, I think your comments -especially the first one- is spot on and that's why I pointed to regression analysis in my answer too. - Just to be clear, I have already upvoted your answer.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends. That’s a very broad question.

Permutation testing is one way, of many, for hypothesis testing. In contrast to the more common tests based on sampling distribution, permutation tests tend to be more conservative to accept new evidence (lower power) and less sensitive to assumptions about the population. A downside of these tests is they’re very computationally intensive and impractical for medium or large datasets.

So permutation tests are appropriate for A/B testing if you’re willing to make these trade offs.

Comment: In Online A/B testing, we have rarely big data(max 100k user's information). But I want to ask what is the other methods ? Do you have any resource to learn these methods ?